# Finding null pointer after environment variables

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I'm reading a book(*Assembly Language Step by Step, Programming with Linux* by Jeff Duntemann) and I'm trying to change this program that show's arguments to instead show the environment variables. I'm trying to only use what was taught thus far(no C) and I've gotten the program to print environment variables but only after I counted how many I had and used an immediate, obviously not satisfying. Here's what I have:

```
global  _start          ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!

_start:
    nop         ; This no-op keeps gdb happy...

    mov ebp,esp     ; Save the initial stack pointer in EBP
; Copy the command line argument count from the stack and validate it:
    cmp dword [ebp],MAXARGS ; See if the arg count exceeds MAXARGS
    ja Error        ; If so, exit with an error message

; Here we calculate argument lengths and store lengths in table ArgLens:
    xor eax,eax     ; Searching for 0, so clear AL to 0
    xor ebx,ebx     ; Stack address offset starts at 0
ScanOne:
    mov ecx,0000ffffh   ; Limit search to 65535 bytes max
    mov edi,dword [ebp+16+ebx*4] ; Put address of string to search in EDI
    mov edx,edi     ; Copy starting address into EDX                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    cld         ; Set search direction to up-memory
    repne scasb     ; Search for null (0 char) in string at edi
    jnz Error       ; REPNE SCASB ended without finding AL
    mov byte [edi-1],10 ; Store an EOL where the null used to be
    sub edi,edx     ; Subtract position of 0 from start address
    mov dword [ArgLens+ebx*4],edi   ; Put length of arg into table
    inc ebx         ; Add 1 to argument counter
    cmp ebx,44; See if arg counter exceeds argument count
    jb ScanOne      ; If not, loop back and do another one

; Display all arguments to stdout:
    xor esi,esi     ; Start (for table addressing reasons) at 0
Showem:
    mov ecx,[ebp+16+esi*4]  ; Pass offset of the message
    mov eax,4       ; Specify sys_write call
    mov ebx,1       ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Standard Output
    mov edx,[ArgLens+esi*4] ; Pass the length of the message
    int 80H         ; Make kernel call
    inc esi         ; Increment the argument counter
    cmp esi,44  ; See if we've displayed all the arguments
    jb Showem       ; If not, loop back and do another
    jmp Exit        ; We're done! Let's pack it in!
```

I moved the displacement up past the first null pointer to the first environment variable(`[ebp+4+ebx*4] > [ebp+16+ebx*4]`) in both `ScanOne` and `Showem`. When I compare to the number of environment variables I have(44) it will print them just fine without a segfault, comparing to 45 only gives me a segfault.

I've tried using the pointers to compare to zero(in search of null pointer): `cmp dword [ebp+16+ebx*4],0h` but that just returns a segfault. I'm sure that the null pointer comes after the last environment variable in the stack but it's like it won't do anything up to and beyond that.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What happens in gdb? Can you step to the point where the segfault occurs?

Comment: So is that the original program or the modified version? also are you sure you didn't make any +-1 errors?

Comment: It's all original other than what I mentioned below the code section. I must have made some dumb error, after trying to compare to 0h again it worked. My bad, answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if your program has 2, 3, or 0 args, would your code still work?  Each section is separated by a NULL pointer (4 bytes of 0) You could just get the count of parameters and use that as your array index and skip over the args until you get to the NULL bytes.  Now you have your Environment Block:

[image]

```
extern printf, exit

section .data
fmtstr      db  "%s", 10, 0
fmtint      db  "%d", 10, 0

global main

section .text
main:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

    mov     ebx, [ebp + 4]

.SkipArgs:  
    mov     edi, dword [ebp + 4 * ebx]
    inc     ebx
    test    edi, edi
    jnz     .SkipArgs

.ShowEnvBlock:
    mov     edi, dword [ebp + 4 * ebx]
    test    edi, edi
    jz      .NoMore

    push    edi
    push    fmtstr
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4 * 2
    inc     ebx
    jmp     .ShowEnvBlock

.NoMore:    
    push    0
    call    exit
```

Yes I use `printf` here, but you just swap that with your system call.

Comment: This is awesome... Also, if I'm not mistaken since this has the C standard library there would be a pointer to the environment variable table as well as the argument table. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Want to go ahead and apologize, this always happens to me(fix it myself after asking question on stackoverflow). I think when I tried comparing pointer to 0h I typed something wrong. Here's what I did:

```
inc ebx
cmp dword [ebp+16+ebx*4],0h
jnz ScanOne
```

and

```
inc esi
cmp dword [ebp+16+esi*4],0h
jnz Showem
```

This worked.